# Coinbase buy widget not activated

Tags: coinbase-api

I would like to use "https://buy.coinbase.com" widget. I created a "Buy Widgets" in my API access tab and now I have a code but my widget is not activated. How can I activate it ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I actually have the same issue. the error it returns is

```
{"errors":[{"id":"invalid_request","message":"This buy widget has not been activated."}],"warnings":[{"id":"missing_version","message":"Please supply API version (YYYY-MM-DD) as CB-VERSION header","url":"https://developers.coinbase.com/api#versioning"}]}
```

Guess we have to submit a buy widget application. lol